# All my docker containers have the error "Too many open files"

Tags: docker

Since I've added the influxdb container to my docker host all my containers are now reporting the error "Too many open files".

Stopping this container solves the issue... but I could really do with it running!

I've upped my limits to 64k on my host be editing the :

```
ulimit -Hn && ulimit -Sn
64000
64000
```

I also added the following to the compose file for influxdb to include the following:

```
ulimits:
  nproc: 65535
  nofile:
    soft: 20000
    hard: 40000
```

however that didn't fix it either.

I'm at a bit of a loss about what to try now. This might help:

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce-rc1
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   2878a85
 Built:        Tue Apr 11 19:57:43 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce-rc1
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   2878a85
 Built:        Tue Apr 11 19:57:43 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Host version

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: what is the host os distibution your using?

Comment: Added at the end - thanks for the comment.